# WeakReference keeps returning Activity reference after orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, garbage-collection, weak-references

I want to use a WeakReference in my AsyncTask to not leak memory. With the log statements I can see, that the activity reference I get returned from the `get` method is indeed null if I leave the activity over the back button.
However, when I rotate the device, I get returned a working reference, which means I leak memory. Any idea why this happens?

**Update:** It starts showing null as soon as I leave the activity AFTER rotating the device and then open a different app. Could it be that the system just does not see a necessity in cleaning up because my activity is so simple?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    }

    public void startAsyncTask(View v) {
        ExampleAsyncTask exampleAsyncTask = new ExampleAsyncTask(this);
        exampleAsyncTask.execute(210);
    }

    private static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

        ExampleAsyncTask(MainActivity context) {
            activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }

            activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            for (int i = 0; i < integers[0]; i++) {
                publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return "Finished";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
                Log.i("activity", "activity = null");
                return;
            } else
                Log.i("activity", "activity not null");
            activity.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }

            activity.progressBar.setProgress(0);
            activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your Activity code and manifest declaration of that activity?

Comment: the activity is created and destroyed on screen-rotation. The java object of the activity remains the same.

Comment: The purpose of WeakReference is to let go off the reference when the activity is destroyed

Comment: The statement made by @RahulKumar is not correct: after orientation change a new java object is being created for the new activity.

Comment: @azizbekian: thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @azizbekian: can this be happening because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048279/1042124

here the op is doing some task in onProgressUpdate

Comment: No, it returns null properly if I leave the activity over the back button. This is how it should be because I only have the strong reference in the scope of the onProgressUpdate method. For some reason it does not work when I rotate the device, which makes no sense to me

Comment: No, I create and execute it on button click

Comment: No, the system destroys the activity

Comment: Update: It shows null if I leave the activity after rotating it and then open a different app. Could it be that the system just doesnt clean up because its not necessary in my simple activity? I tested it with a strong reference and then the same behavior does NOT show null.

Comment: The interesting thing is, that it starts showing null as soon as I start another app

Answer (score 1):

When the activity is being destroyed, the activity object should become eligible for garbage collection. This means, that some of the next GC events would free up memory hold by the activity.

You are making an assumption, that GC have to occur immediately after you perform orientation change, which is not true. What `WeakReference` ensures, is that it will not be a reason to hold the object when next time GC will try to clear up memory. Sooner or later the activity object would be cleared by GC, but it will not take place instantly as you expect.

You can utilize `System.gc()` which will initiate a synchronous GC event to take place, but it's not advised to rely on this method in normal scenario.

```
    System.gc();
    MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
    // now `activity` should be null
```

Comment: Even when I try it like this it isn't null. I don't understand that. It works when I leave over the back button. I also tried running it for 30 seconds

Comment: That means, that you are keeping a reference to the activity from somewhere else. Use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to find out where from.

Comment: As soon as a I added LeakCanary, it started working (instead of showing a notification). When I remove it, it stops working. I don't understand what is happening

Comment: I've added the complete activity code. I don't see any spot where I hold a reference

Comment: Update: It shows null if I leave the activity after rotating it and then open a different app. Could it be that the system just doesnt clean up because its not necessary in my simple activity? I tested it with a strong reference and then the same behavior does NOT show null.

Comment: The interesting thing is, that it starts showing null as soon as I start another app

Comment: @FlorianWalther This is the answer, the only thing is that calling `System.gc()` doesn't work, I'm not sure why, but if you trigger the garbage collector from the memory profile in Android Studio you see the value becoming null right away